# Suitable non-deep classification algorithm for binary images

Tags: classification, image-processing

I've to classify images of hand shapes like this:

[image]

I've tried this methodes actually:

- SVM with contour vector of the hands shape as features
- PCA on images pixels + SVM

Have you other ideas to deal with this situation ?

Comment: A neural network with no hidden layers is logistic regression, and its optimization problem is convex and straightforward.

Comment: What features of these images can I use with a logistic regression ?

Comment: That's something you'll have to feature engineer .  Look into basis expansions.  A neural network is essentially just logistic regression where the feature engineering is done for you recursively across the layers.